# Unable to check mail from other accounts in Gmail using Dovecot/POP3

Tags: dovecot, gmail, pop3

I have a VPS running on AlmaLinux. For SMTP, I use sendmail, which successfully sends and received emails for both of my domain names. I have Dovecot set up to handle IMAP/POP3. I want to allow a Gmail account to get emails from one of my domain names (let's call it example.com) using the "Check mail from other accounts" feature Gmail provides. Unfortunately, I cannot get this to work.

Here is where things stand:

I am pretty sure Dovecot is correctly configured to handle POP3 connections. From my computer, I can enter the following in the command line:

```
openssl s_client -starttls pop3 -connect mail.example.com:110
```

If I then enter `USER fake_username` and `PASS fake_password`, I can execute POP commands (e.g. `LIST` and `STAT`) and get correct responses.

Furthermore, I configured Thunderbird on my local machine to read emails using POP3 from mail.example.com. In Thunderbird, I am able to read emails with the following Account Settings:

```
Server Name: mail.example.com
Port: 110
User Name: fake_username
Connection Security: STARTTLS
Authentication Method: Normal Password
```

...and emails come though without a hitch.

When I use the same information (mail.example.com, port 110, correct username, correct password) in Gmail, however, I get one of two error messages, based on whether I check the checkbox reading "Always use a secure connection (SSL) when retrieving mail."

If I leave the checkbox unchecked, on the web form, I see the following error message:

"Server denied POP3 access for the given username and password."

On my server log (`dovecot.log`), I see the following:

```
Mar 19 12:27:36 pop3-login: Info: Disconnected: Disconnected: Too many bad commands (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=209.85.128.137, lip=103.72.79.234, session=<cR/KSUP3MIvRVYCJ>
```

If I check the "always use SSL" checbox, on the front end Gmail shows this error message:

"There was a problem connecting to mail.example.com"

And in `dovecot.log`, I see:

```
Mar 19 12:27:01 pop3-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: before SSL initialization
Mar 19 12:27:01 pop3-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: before SSL initialization
Mar 19 12:27:01 pop3-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: before SSL initialization
Mar 19 12:27:01 pop3-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: before SSL initialization
Mar 19 12:27:01 pop3-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: before SSL initialization
Mar 19 12:27:01 pop3-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS read client hello
Mar 19 12:27:01 pop3-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write server hello
Mar 19 12:27:01 pop3-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write change cipher spec
Mar 19 12:27:01 pop3-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: TLSv1.3 write encrypted extensions
Mar 19 12:27:01 pop3-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write certificate
Mar 19 12:27:01 pop3-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: TLSv1.3 write server certificate verify
Mar 19 12:27:01 pop3-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write finished
Mar 19 12:27:01 pop3-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: TLSv1.3 early data
Mar 19 12:27:01 pop3-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: TLSv1.3 early data
Mar 19 12:27:01 pop3-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: TLSv1.3 early data
Mar 19 12:27:01 pop3-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: TLSv1.3 early data
Mar 19 12:27:01 pop3-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: TLSv1.3 early data
Mar 19 12:27:01 pop3-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: TLSv1.3 early data
Mar 19 12:27:01 pop3-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS read finished
Mar 19 12:27:01 pop3-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x20, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
Mar 19 12:27:01 pop3-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
Mar 19 12:27:01 pop3-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
Mar 19 12:27:01 pop3-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=1: SSL negotiation finished successfully
Mar 19 12:27:01 pop3-login: Info: Login: user=<fake_username>, method=PLAIN, rip=71.232.112.192, lip=[MY SERVER'S IP ADDRESS], mpid=949498, TLS, session=<waq2R0P3fM1H6HDA>
Mar 19 12:27:01 pop3(fake_username)<949498><waq2R0P3fM1H6HDA>: Info: Disconnected: Logged out top=0/0, retr=0/0, del=0/0, size=0
Mar 19 12:27:01 pop3-login: Debug: SSL alert: close notify
```

In my file `/etc/dovecot/10-auth.conf`, the only lines I have uncommented are:

```
auth_mechanisms = plain login
!include auth-system.conf.ext
```

And there is nothing related to auth in `dovecot.conf`

I assume there is some mismatch between how I am authorizing the session via command line and in Thunderbird on the one hand (Thunderbird can't connect to mail.example.com via POP3 unless I use `STARTTLS`), and how Gmail is trying to connect on the other hand. Unfortunately, the error logs are all Greek to me, and I can't make enough sense of the Dovecot documentation to figure out how to let Dovecot grant access to Gmail.

Does any kind soul understand what is/might be going on here and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google doesn't expect STARTTLS. They expect POP3S, probably on port 995. You have to enable this in dovecot.

Comment: Thank you so much. For anyone else struggling with this in the future:

I went into my dovecot file 10-master.conf and added the following lines:

service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3 {
    port = 110
  }
  inet_listener pop3s {
    port = 995
    ssl = yes
  }
}

NB, in dovecot.conf, I only set the protocols to imap and pop -- Dovecot threw a warning when I added pop3s. So in dovecot.conf I have:

protocols = pop3 imap

In Gmail, I just entered my username/pw, mail.example.com, set the port to 995, and checked the "always use SSL" checkbox, and everything worked.